# 'Add file'/'Remove file' in channel entry not working, console errors

Tags: file-uploads

All of a sudden, I'm unable to add/remove files (using a vanilla file field) from channel entries. No dialog appears, no error in the page.

The console does show errors - but I'm not sure how to address them:

```
> Found third party scripts in <head> tag.
  Please use cp->add_to_foot() to add scripts. jQuery and the EE global will be moved down in a future release.
  [Inline Script]
x Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'uniform' admin.php?S=41030c226a249b2e59509a17309f7282&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=6&entry…:2005
x Uncaught ReferenceError: _EE_uploader_attached is not defined
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you update to EE 2.8 recently? What add-ons, specifically fieldtypes are you using?

Comment: This is a 2.7.3 install. The only add-on I installed is Matrix, (in Matrix fields I'm not having any issues uploading files).

Comment: I'm having this identical issue (the third party message and add_to_foot, not the others) with my 2.7.3 install. In my instance, the vanilla upload field is in a matrix and is just showing `{filedir_2}filename.jpg` instead of the upload control.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by comparing my current EE installation with a previous installation. The `<head>` of my 'admin.php' file was missing references to js files that my previous installation had:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/jquery.uniform.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

I made sure these files existed, added these references to `admin.php`, and uploads are working.